# PHP preg_match: "Text-Text-Integer" gives Unknown modifier '-'

Tags: php

I have the following code that checks if a domain has the pattern "Text-Text-Integer". However I get the error Unknown modifier '-' because the - inside is not escaped. I tried to add \ before - but it does not help.

```
<?php

$get_keyword_value = "([a-zA-Z])-([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])";
$get_current_domain_value = "domain-id-555";

if(preg_match($get_keyword_value, $get_current_domain_value)){
    echo"Match";
}
else{
    echo"No match";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pattern to this:-

```
$get_keyword_value = "/([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9])/";
```

(Edit:- forgot to add ending colon)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern needs to be delimited with a character, such as `"/([a-zA-Z])-([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])/"`, `"@([a-zA-Z])-([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])@"`, `"#([a-zA-Z])-([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])#"` or whatever.

This allows you to pass [modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) like `"/([a-zA-Z])-([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])/i"` for a case insensitive match, in example.

`"([a-zA-Z])-([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])"` will use the `()` as delimiter. Then, the engine tries to use the modifiers, and the first one is `-` which doesn't exist.

*Side note : Your pattern won't match the input, because `([a-zA-Z])` will search for a **single** character, but this is another topic*